# symfony 2 create multitenants database

Tags: php, database, symfony

I have a multitenants project that requires me to use Symfony 2.

I have followed [this tutorial](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/symfony2-dynamic-subdomains) with success. I have 2 Entity managers. 1 for the global tenant database and another for each tenant's DB connection. It is dynamically updating the connection to use different DB with every different subdomain.

I am now stuck in how to create new DB and new DB User when there is a registration.
My questions are:

1. What is the best Symfony way to achieve this?
2. What is the best workflow so I can update every single tenants' DB everytime there is structure update?

Thanks!